# Can't Run two voice and a thread together

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a clock where if the `minutes <= 10` a warning voice would be played.
But when `minutes <= 10` the `warningVoice()` method is running but the clock is paused till the voice will over. After the voice will over the clock is start again.

How can I run the warning voice and the clock simultaneously so that the clock does not stop during the `warningVoice()`?

Voice Code:

```
private void warningVoice() {
    System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
    vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    voice = vm.getVoice(SayWhat);
    voice.setStyle("robotic");
    voice.setVolume(200);
    voice.allocate();
    String writing; 
    writing = "You Have" + lblMinute.getText() + "Minutes Left";
    try {
        voice.speak(writing);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Clock Code:

```
private void showTime() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            second--;
            second_format = String.format("%02d", second);
            minute_format = String.format("%02d", minute);

            lblSecond.setText(String.valueOf(second_format));

            if (second == -1) {
                second = 59;
                minute--;
                second_format = String.format("%02d", second);
                minute_format = String.format("%02d", minute);
                lblSecond.setText(String.valueOf(second_format));
                lblMinute.setText(String.valueOf(minute_format));
             
               /*This is the problem line*/
                if (minute <= 10) {
                    warningVoice();
                }
                
                if (minute == 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    
                    second = 60;
                    minute = 25;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Currently the `warningVoice()` code is running on the _same_ thread as your `ActionListener`. You'd want to dispatch the call to `warningVoice` through a different thread (either through an `ExecutorService`, or some other service offered by whatever API is available to you. For example swing and javafx both have methods to invoke things off of the main gui thread). To be honest, I think a `ScheduledExecutorService` might make things a lot easier here than `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the util Timer class and TimerTasks then you can greatly simplify your code with something like this:

```
private void warningVoice(long millisLeft) {
    //obviously replace this with your voice code
    System.out.println("You have " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisLeft) + " minutes left");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    long taskTimeInMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(25);
    final long warningTimeInMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);
    long sendWarning = taskTimeInMillis - warningTimeInMillis;

    TimerTask warningTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            warningVoice(warningTimeInMillis);
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(warningTask, sendWarning);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't set the `lblSecond` and `lblMinute` where the OP probably wants to update some Swing labels to show the remaining time.

Comment: @cyberbrain  yes, I would expect him to edit the code to meet his needs.  My goal is to show him a better way to handle the functionality, not solve his problem 100%

Comment: @Ryan Sorry I Can't perform with your code :( Will you please give a solution that helps me.

Comment: This does run, but you probably need to import the java.util.Timer class to use it. You're using the javax.swing.Timer.